# object first jump travels much higher?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-physics

I am having trouble figuring out how to make an object "jump" in Unity. The cube(player) seems to travel much higher the first time the spacebar is pressed compared to any subsequent jumps:[image]

Here is the code to move the object, basically all the code in the project really. Note that I am a day 1 beginner to Unity so it is likely I am doing something in some obviously wrong or disgustingly bad way. All I want is for the cube to jump the same distance every time spacebar is pressed.

```
void FixedUpdate() {
    float moveHorizontal = (Input.GetAxis("Horizontal")/10);
    float moveVertical = (Input.GetAxis("Vertical")/10 * -1);
    rigidbody.MovePosition(new Vector3 (rigidbody.position.x + moveVertical, rigidbody.position.y,rigidbody.position.z + moveHorizontal));
    if (Input.GetKeyDown("space")) {
        rigidbody.AddForce(Vector3.up * 5, ForceMode.Impulse);
}
```

Comment: @ScottChamberlain: float per [the documentation](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetAxis.html)

Comment: There is nothing stopping you from holding the space key down and going up higher and higher in this logic, could that be the problem?

Comment: I don't believe so, besides, I use GetKeyDown(), so even if I was rapidly pressing the spacebar (which I am not) the movement would be jankier, right?

Comment: Oh, `GetKeyDown` only gets called once per keypress. My next guess would be to check your physics system, maybe some property of the rigidbody isn't being set correctly, dunno if I can help other than that suggestion.

Comment: Have you tried changing the force mode to force instead of impulse?

Comment: I think I have but I'll give it a try. I made a beeline for impulse because it ignores mass and I have no idea how much force is needed to move a certain mass…